# yii2-admin как сделать свои поля для регистрации

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Поставил модуль https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin, добавил пару строк в бд (которые мне нужны), во view тоже их добавил.

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use mdm\admin\models\form\Signup as SignupForm;

public $address;
public $name;
public $surname;

class Signup extends SignupForm
{
}
```

Унаследовал модель. Как теперь правильно сделать, чтобы поля сохранялись в бд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace app\models;

use mdm\admin\models\form\Signup as SignupForm;

public $address;
public $name;
public $surname;

class Signup extends SignupForm
{

...

 public function signup()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $this->username;
            $user->email = $this->email;
            $user->setPassword($this->password);
            $user->generateAuthKey();
            
            $user->address = $this->address;
            $user->name = $this->name;
            $user->surname = $this->surname;
            
            if ($user->save()) {
                return $user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
...
}
```